# RESTful JSON based SOA Registry

Tags: json, web-services, http, rest, soa

I'm searching for a simple registry which provides a very simple API and works with resources that can be described as JSON.

I'm designing a Resource Oriented Architecture (entirely HTTP REST, no WS-*'s ESB or other things, all communications are made over network, are stateless and all services share nothing) that will be all talking using JSON as primary data, so I'm a bit bored to use XML only to work with that SOA Registry.

*Disclaimer: I really love WSO2 stuff, I learned SOA looking at what they provide. The reason I didn't choose their registry is because from samples I've looked at it didn't seem to be possibile to use JSON.*

Comment: The question in nutshell is in the topic. And it was not answered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get it. Is the semantics of the JSON you store relevant to the "registry" server at all? Because if not, any JSON storage engine with a REST CRUD API should be OK, like CouchDB, etc.
You then do HTTP access control to only allow your service providing entities to add entries about themselves, and clients may only read.

Or should this "registry" actually do something with the data, like periodically actively test service availability and update reachability status? Because that sounds like a separate concern from storage and serving of the data, thus can be a separate component.

Comment: I want to describe each service using JSON instead of using the standard UDDI because it's based on XML. Since what I'm building will be entirely working with JSON it would be an useless loss of time to implement into each service XML just for service discovery... Of course I need to know about services' status, and maybe have an integration with Nagios for reporting.